# Waypoints Horizontal Plug in, Can't get simple demo to work, what am I missing?

Tags: plugins, scroll, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to get this horizontal scrolling Plugin from Waypoints to work and it appears that there must be something outside of my knowledge that is missing.

Here's a codepen I made of the 1 and only example they had. It's supposed to trigger a little pop up notifier. Firstly, I'd like to see that this really works before I put anymore time/frustration into it - but I'd also like to attach an addClass or toggleClass to it.

```js
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('horizontal-waypoint-offset'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    notify('right-in-view waypoint triggered')
  },
  context: document.getElementById('overflow-scroll-offset'),
  horizontal: true,
  offset: 'right-in-view'
})
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/code-a-la-mode/pen/vOPWgM

Demo on Waypoint site:http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/horizontal-option/

(ultimate use for this: I have a vimeo frame that slides in from an absolute left offscreen. I plan to have this toggle play/pause as it enters/leaves the viewport.)

I'd appreciate just seeing this work in any capacity, but if anyone wants to show off and make an example of it controlling play/pause as a vimeo (or youtube) screen slides in from off screen, I wouldn't mind AT ALL :)

Answer (score 0):

The version of Waypoints you're using in that Pen is very old, 1.1.6. Creating waypoints using `new Waypoint` wasn't a feature until 3.0. Please try updating.